# CheckBox in dataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

After file is added - Instead of seeing "Yes" in the dataGridView column, I want a checked CheckBox. How do I get do to do this?

What I am doing:

In the “main” form when I click “Add” then the frmAddVideo appears where I need to insert all the video’s information. In the frmAddVideo form there is a comboBox with values “Yes” and “No” for the availability of the video. When “Yes” is selected then the video displayed in the dataGridVideo after it is added, there must be a “ticked” checkbox in the dataGridView and vice versa for when it’s not available.

I provided code but I don’t think it is correct seeing that it does not work. I am not providing the main form because it is not necessary.

frmAddVideo

```
namespace A6
{
    public partial class FrmAddVideo : Form
    {
        internal Video NewVideo;
        public FrmAddVideo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //ADD VIDEO
        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                NewVideo = new Video();

                NewVideo.Title = textBox1.Text;
                NewVideo.Category = Convert.ToString(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
                NewVideo.YearReleased = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value);
                NewVideo.RunTime = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);

                //AVAILABILITY
                //How do I make this to apear as a checkbox in the dataGridView?
                NewVideo.Availability = Convert.ToString(comboBox2.SelectedItem);

                if (NewVideo.yesNo() == true)
                    MessageBox.Show("Yes");
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("No");


                MessageBox.Show("Video added");
                this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

frmViewVideo

```
namespace A6
{
    public partial class frmViewVideo : Form
    {
        internal Video NewVideo;
        public frmViewVideo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void frmViewVideo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = NewVideo.Title;
            textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(NewVideo.RunTime);
            numericUpDown1.Value = NewVideo.YearReleased;
            comboBox1.SelectedItem = Convert.ToString(NewVideo.Category);
            comboBox2.SelectedItem = Convert.ToString(NewVideo.Availability);
        }
    }
}
```

Class

```
namespace A6
{
    [Serializable]

    class Video
    {
        private string mTitle;
        private string mCategory;
        private int mYearReleased;
        private double mRunTime;
        private string mAvailability;

        //bool mshowing3D;

        public string Title
        {
            get { return mTitle; }
            set { mTitle = value; }
        }

        public string Category
        {
            get { return mCategory; }
            set { mCategory = value; }
        }

        public int YearReleased
        {
            get { return mYearReleased; }
            set { mYearReleased = value; }
        }

        public double RunTime
        {
            get { return mRunTime; }
            set { mRunTime = value; }
        }

        public string Availability
        {
            get { return mAvailability; }
            set { mAvailability = value; }
        }

        public bool yesNo()
        {
            if (mAvailability == "Yes")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        //CONSTRUCTOR
        public Video()
        {
            mTitle = "No Name";
            mCategory = "No Category";
            mYearReleased = 0;
            mRunTime = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The rest of the application works perfectly. Just can't figure out what to do with the bool statement for availability.

Thanks a lot guys!

J

Comment: You posted a lot of code, and yet, I can't find your DataGridView control anywhere in it.  Even your Add Video code doesn't show it being added to anything.  Having your Availability property be a string is probably a mistake, since you are treating it as a bool.

Answer (score 0):

Firs create a new checkbox in your form like this :

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="SelectCheckBox" runat="server" />
```

Then change the MessageBox Control to a CheckBox and Pass a Value to its checked property:

```
//AVAILABILITY
                //How do I make this to apear as a checkbox in the dataGridView?
                NewVideo.Availability = Convert.ToString(comboBox2.SelectedItem);

                                SelectCheckBox.Checked = NewVideo.yesNo();
```

Comment: also you can make checkbox unavailable to cahange by user, setting its `Enabled` property to false in your CodeBehind;

Comment: Is there another way to create a checkbox? I'm asking because I'm not using servers or any database at the moment.

Comment: The question is tagged `Winforms`.

Comment: you can create a checkbox in codeBehind (c# file) like this : `CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();` and then you can iterate over its properties.